Using command in newgeometry
Please, help me understand why following does not work:
\def\test{layoutwidth=100mm}
\newgeometry{\test}

And just throws "Package keyval Error: layoutwidth=100mm undefined." error,
while this:
\newgeometry{layoutwidth=100mm,}

Works perfectly fine?

welcome! because the stuff interpreting the option list doesn't expand \test. try \ExpandArgs {e} \newgeometry{\test}. (but I'm not good at predicting expansion, so don't be surprised if it doesn't work.)

(but it does work, as it happens.)

Welcome to TeX.SX! Please don't post code fragments. Instead, put your fragments into a complete compilable document that shows the problem.

\expanded{\noexpand\newgeometry{\test}} or \expandafter\newgeometry\expandafter{\test} but the former is able to handle arbitrary location of \test among other options.
